# using react-router-dom Link with styled components renders nothing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` for the first time and facing some issue while using Link form `react-router-dom` v6.
Nothing is rendered with the current code but when I remove the `Link` tag code works fine. Please help.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/">
      <HomeButton>Place Order</HomeButton>
    </Link>
  );
};

const HomeButton = styled.button`
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Space Grotesk", sans-serif;

  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: white;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 2px 2px rgba(99, 99, 99, 1);
`;

export default Home;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console ?

Comment: Your code is working as expected in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-router-dom-link-with-styled-components-renders-nothing-849wom). Are there any errors in your console? What is the output you observe? Can you try creating your own *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react router dom v6 requires  your navabar component and <Route path= element={}/>  if you need to use link.

```
<Router >
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<div><h1>Home Page</h1></div>}/>
      <Route path="register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Negative. The only thing the `Link` needs is a routing context provided by a router component higher up in the ReactTree.